# Convert blank node in URI in sparql

Tags: sparql, blank-nodes

I would like to convert blank nodes into URIs using a SPARQL query. Imagine something like:

```
_:N58f332639cbd46d6a5ec9410e5d875a7 <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://schema.org/WebSite> .
_:N3b2eed756126458582bba185ab0fdb0b <http://schema.org/name> "Chefkoch.de" .
_:N3b2eed756126458582bba185ab0fdb0b <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://schema.org/Organization> .
```

then I would like a query like:

```
SELECT (func(?s) as ?s1) ?p ?o where {
    ?s ?p ?o
}
```

and func should convert the blank nodes in some URIs.

I find it quite a frequent use case but could not find a solution ....

Comment: Can you define "some URIs" part? Would newly assigned URIs work for your case? Also, what implementation of RDF store and SPARQL engine are you using?

Comment: Can you also send the larger chunk of your data?

Comment: I don't get where exactly the problem is, I mean, a URI or IRI can be create via function `URI` or `IRI` - that's it. There question is more, shall it only be in the resultset of the `SELECT` query? Or are we talking about modifying the existing graph, which simply means  replace each bnode in each occuring position by an IRI  - by the way we also refer to this as skolemization in RDF, e.g. https://www.w3.org/2011/rdf-wg/wiki/Skolemisation

Comment: Hi, my initial test was like SELECT (IRI(?s) as ?s1) ?p ?o where {?s ?p ?o} but the result of s1 is blank. According to the standard https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/ the function IRI does not accept blank nodes. As of which SPARQL endpoint, I tried RDF4J. I think it is pretty adhering to the standard.

Answer (score -1):

```
DELETE {
?subject ?predicate ?o.

    }
INSERT {
?newUri ?predicate ?o .

}    
WHERE { select * where {
?subject ?predicate ?o .
BIND(IRI(CONCAT(STR("https://domain.nl/resource"), "/", STRAFTER(STR(?subject), "_:"))) AS ?newUri)
FILTER(isBlank(?subject)) 
}
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could format your answer and add an explanation.